# Global variables in swift do not change

Tags: ios, swift, global-variables

I created a couple global variables for my app to load an image as well as a string. When I try to change the value they stay the same however. The value doesn't change after the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is called it is still "initial".

```
import UIKit

var testString = "initial"

class SubjectsViewController: UIViewController {

.....

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { imageData, error in
            if (error == nil) {
                selectedPhoto = UIImage(data: imageData)!
                println("Should change variables")
                testString = "testing"
                println("no error in fetching image")
            } else {
                println("There is an error getting image")
            }
        }

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detailSegue", sender: self)
    }
```

Comment: You mean it isn't set after you call an asynchronous function?

Comment: How did you check that the value does not change? Are you aware that `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` works *asynchronously*? The closure (which changes the global variable) is called at a later time when the data has been retrieved. – Lookup "return value from asynchronous method", there are many similar Q&A.

Comment: i have been tested that, globally declared variable we can do changes with that object. better test it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that hold all the global variables of the application

```
 class GlobalVariables : NSObject {
       var testString = "initial"
    }
    var global = GlobalVariables()
```

so now in your class use the code as

```
 if (error == nil) {
                selectedPhoto = UIImage(data: imageData)!
                println("Should change variables")
// Global variable as now this will work and its value will be not be remove until the application is close , and change until y             
                global.testString = "testing"
                println("no error in fetching image")
```

Comment: Why do you need global variables for this?

Comment: creating a global variable in every controller so better to create a single global class that hold all the variables and u can use the variable in any of the controller in application

Comment: But that should be a rare situation. It's a good idea to remind people about how infrequently globals are the correct solution...

Comment: yah :) here for this it can also be a good solution just give it a try